# How to overwrite/update an encrypted column with SQLAlchemy when the encryption key is lost?

Tags: python, flask, encryption, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy with SQlite in a Flask application.
I have a model called User:

```
class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)  
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True) 
    otp_secret  = db.Column(EncryptedType( db.Unicode, get_user_personal_key))
    ...
```

I used encryptedType to encrypt a column of the model User called otp_secret using a dynamic key generated from the user password hash. When the user logs in, the key is generated and stored in the session. Then SQLAlchemy use the key from the session returned by the callback function get_user_personal_key() to decrypt the column otp_secret.

If the user want to change the password, I do the following:

- Generate the encryption/decryption key from the old password and store it in the session,
- Request data UserX from the database so SQLAlchemy uses the key from the session to decrypt otp_secret
- Generate the new encryption/decryption key from the new password and overwrite the old key in the session.
- Save UserX to database so SQLAlchemy uses the new encryption key to encrypt the column otp_secret

Till now everything is working fine but what if the user lost his password? Please how can I overwrite the old otp_secret without having the old encryption key if it's possible?

Comment: The point of encrypting is so someone without the key won't be able to read/process/whatever the encrypted info, so if you lost the key I think you're stuck.

Comment: You are right and I don't want to decrypt the old otp_secret but generate a new value and update the User table with it.

Comment: So you want to replace the old value completely?

Comment: You need a workaround, not something real simple. If the user lost their password, you need a mechanism to let them set a new password based on the knowledge they are the actual user. A simple example would be password reset through email. You are trusting the email of the user, you send a new key to their email or any other mechanism how you want to let them set the new password.

Comment: Yes, I want ton replace the old value completely. I send confirmation code via email. The problem is  that I cannot overwrite the old value with SQLAlchemy without the old encryption key. To update a User element, I have to get that user first from database example : userX =  User.query.filter_by(email="<some_email@address>").first()  only after that I can set the new otp_secret value like this : userX,otp_secret = gen_otp_sec(). Is there a way to write to DB without reading or at least without decrypting a column?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the database using a sql query.

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2 ... WHERE column_name = something
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this.

Comment: @Ahmed the `WHERE` part is optional.